# Unable to output model to torchsummary

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I want to print summary my model with torchsummary but it print just part of model.

So I tried print(), but it's printed still part of model.

This is my model class(ResNet 34)

```
class ResNet_compat(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 input_shape=(3, 224, 224),
                 blocks_in_model=[3, 4, 6, 3],
                 layers_in_block=[2, 2, 2, 2],
                 kernel_sizes=[(3,3), (3,3), (3,3), (3,3)],
                 channel_sizes=[(64,64), (128,128), (256,256), (512,512)],
                 class_size=2,
                 is_plain=False):

        super(ResNet_compat, self).__init__()

        self.input_shape=input_shape
        self.blocks_in_model=blocks_in_model
        self.layers_in_block=layers_in_block
        self.kernel_sizes=kernel_sizes
        self.channel_sizes=channel_sizes
        self.class_size=class_size
        self.is_plain=is_plain
        
        # conv1+conv2 maxpooling
        self.conv1=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True),
            nn.ReLU(), 
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(3,3), stride=2, padding=1)
        )

        
        self.block_forms=list()
        for i in range(len(blocks_in_model)):
            for j in range(blocks_in_model[i]):
                
                # i는 group, j는 block
                if i==0 and j==0:
                    inp_channel=64
                elif i!=0 and j==0:
                    inp_channel=channel_sizes[i-1][-1]
                else:
                    inp_channel=False

                self.block_forms.append(self.build_block(
                    self.layers_in_block[i],
                    kernel_sizes=self.kernel_sizes[i],
                    channel_sizes=self.channel_sizes[i],
                    input_channel=inp_channel,
                    is_plain=False
                ))

        
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

        self.end_avg2d=nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1,1))
        self.end_linear=nn.Linear(in_features=self.channel_sizes[-1][-1], out_features=2, bias=True)
        self.end_softmax=nn.Softmax(-1)
    
    def build_block(self, layers, kernel_sizes, channel_sizes, input_channel, is_plain=False):
        
        full_block=[]
        for i in range(layers):
            if kernel_sizes[i]!= 1:
                layer_padding=(1,1)
            else:
                layer_padding=(0,0)

            if input_channel and i==0:
                if input_channel != channel_sizes[i]:
                    f_stride=2
                else:
                    f_stride=1
                full_block.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=input_channel, 
                                            out_channels=channel_sizes[i], 
                                            kernel_size=kernel_sizes[i],
                                            padding=layer_padding,
                                            stride=f_stride,
                                            bias=False
                                            ))
            else:
                full_block.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=channel_sizes[i-1],
                                            out_channels=channel_sizes[i],
                                            kernel_size=kernel_sizes[i],
                                            padding=layer_padding,
                                            bias=False
                                            ))
            # batch_normalization
            full_block.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(channel_sizes[i], eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True))

            if i< layers-1:
                full_block.append(nn.ReLU())

        return nn.Sequential(*full_block)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.shape)
        x=self.conv1(x)
        print(x.shape)

        # model body
        for block in self.block_forms:
            identity=x
            x=block(x)

            if block[0].in_channels != block[0].out_channels:
                self.reduce=nn.Conv2d(
                    block[0].in_channels,
                    block[0].out_channels,
                    kernel_size=(1,1),
                    stride=2)
                identity=self.reduce(identity)
            
            x+=identity
            x=self.relu(x)


        x=self.end_avg2d(x)
        x=torch.flatten(x, 1, -1)
        x=self.end_linear(x)
        x=self.end_softmax(x)
       
        return x
```

And the following is the result of executing summary() and print().

```
# summary
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1         [-1, 64, 112, 112]           9,408
       BatchNorm2d-2         [-1, 64, 112, 112]             128
              ReLU-3         [-1, 64, 112, 112]               0
         MaxPool2d-4           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
              ReLU-5           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
              ReLU-6           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
              ReLU-7           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
              ReLU-8          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
              ReLU-9          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
             ReLU-10          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
             ReLU-11          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
             ReLU-12          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
             ReLU-13          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
             ReLU-14          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
             ReLU-15          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
             ReLU-16          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
             ReLU-17          [-1, 256, 14, 14]               0
             ReLU-18            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
             ReLU-19            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
             ReLU-20            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
AdaptiveAvgPool2d-21            [-1, 512, 1, 1]               0
           Linear-22                    [-1, 2]           1,026
          Softmax-23                    [-1, 2]               0
================================================================
Total params: 10,562
Trainable params: 10,562
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.57
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 30.44
Params size (MB): 0.04
Estimated Total Size (MB): 31.05
----------------------------------------------------------------


# print
ResNet_compat(
  (conv1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
    (1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (2): ReLU()
    (3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (relu): ReLU()
  (end_avg2d): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
  (end_linear): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2, bias=True)
  (end_softmax): Softmax(dim=-1)
  (reduce): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2))
)
```

Maybe overlapping blocks are the problem.
In the code I wrote, 'build_block()' is a code that creates a block of resnet, and forward() uses a method of connecting blocks one by one in a for statement by receiving a list of blocks generated by build_block().

If there is no problem with the model configuration, it doesn't matter if the output is not properly from summary() and print(), but it's hard to see the situation where the model isn't output properly as normal, so I want to check if it's possible.